# Bold or normal font for coding

Tags: fonts

is it better to use bold or normal font for programming coding.
We choose some of good fonts (Inconsolata, Source Code Pro).
Some of the screencasts out there use Source Code Pro BOLD and it looks very good. It is easy to rea/write code with that font bolded.

I wonder if it is good for the eyes if you code 8,9 hours per day with bold font, or it's better to use normal font (not bolded).

Answer (score -1):

You may want to checkout [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)
Also here are some good articles about best colors on the eyes:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53264/dark-or-white-color-theme-is-better-for-the-eyes

http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-color-schemes-for-Sublime-Text-2

Comment: Thanks, there are many good themes, but i ask about BOLD or NORMAL text. I thing code is more readable bolded, but maybe there will be problem with the eyes if you stare whole day. I dont know really :)